# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I really need help here, it's an easy problem that I'm struggling with because I don't know where is the issue here. Whenever I try to insert a photo in my jupyter notebook I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

even tho I downloaded the picture and it's definitely in my PC. Can anyone here help me please, here are the pictures (any help will be much appreciated):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please convert every single image to text.

Comment: filepath should be `desktop/img/bitcoin.jpg`